# Spark-shell does not import specified jar file

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra, spark-cassandra-connector, spark-shell

I am a complete beginner to all this stuff in general so pardon if I'm missing some totally obvious step. I installed spark 3.1.2 and cassandra 3.11.11 and I'm trying to connect both of them through this [guide](https://www.batey.info/spark-cassandra-basics-connecting-to.html) I found where I made a fat jar for execution. In the link I posted when they execute the spark-shell command with the jar file, there's a line which occurs at the start.

`INFO SparkContext: Added JAR file:/home/chbatey/dev/tmp/spark-cassandra-connector/spark-cassandra-connector-java/target/scala-2.10/spark-cassandra-connector-java-assembly-1.2.0-SNAPSHOT.jar at http://192.168.0.34:51235/jars/spark-15/01/26 16:16:10 INFO SparkILoop: Created spark context..`

I followed all of the steps properly but it doesn't show any line like that in my shell. To confirm that it hasn't been added I try the sample program on that website and it throws an error

`java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/datastax/spark/connector/util/Logging`

What should I do? I'm using spark-cassandra-connector-3.1.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to compile it yourself, just follow official [documentation](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/master/doc/0_quick_start.md) - use `--packages` to automatically download all dependencies:

```
spark-shell --packages com.datastax.spark:spark-cassandra-connector_2.12:3.1.0
```

Your error is that connector file doesn't contain dependencies, you need to list all things, like, java driver, etc.  So if you still want to use `--jars` option, then just download [assembly version](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.datastax.spark/spark-cassandra-connector-assembly_2.12/3.1.0) of it ([link to jar](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/datastax/spark/spark-cassandra-connector-assembly_2.12/3.1.0/spark-cassandra-connector-assembly_2.12-3.1.0.jar)) - it will contain all necessary dependencies.

Comment: So about that, I already used that command and the connector still wasn't working. Gave me the same error I mentioned so I resorted to using a fat JAR instead.

Comment: Okay never mind that worked. I realised I hadn't tried the assembly jar method yet.